# Dividing 3d image to equal submatrix using mat2cell()

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I have a 3d image of 128x128x128 that I want to divide it to 8 equal submatrix writing `mat2cell(I,[64x64],[64x64],[64x64])` for future processing. My problem is when I try to concatenate the submatrix, the output image size is 128x128x2?? Can anyone give me a 
help??

```
> clc,clear,close all;  
> f=phantom3d(128);  
> theta=0:179;  
> C=mat2cell(f,[64,64],[64,64],[64,64]);  
> tic;  
> matlabpool(2)  
> parfor i=1:8
> wx=C{i}; 
> g=radon(wx,theta);
> g=iradon(g,theta,size(C{i},1));
> C{i}=g;

> end 
> conct=cell2mat(C);

> matlabpool close

> Reconstruction_time=toc
> figure, imshow3D(conct,[]),title('Filtered Backprojection image');
```

Comment: What the size of `g` within each iteration?

Comment: g contains the radon and iradon transform to each submatrix so the size is 64x64x64

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With the information you provide it's hard for us to help

Comment: As far as I know, MATLAB's `radon` and `iradon` only do two dimensional data. So, the output from each `iradon` will be a 64x64 matrix, which when you arrange them back into one array with cell2mat will make a 128x128x2 matrix. What's your aim? Are you trying to take the 2D Radon transform along each slice of your 3D arrays? In that case you'll probably need to loop over the slices.